# Hiding and re-arranging attribute table columns in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes

This used to be possible by right-clicking column headings in the attribute table, then using the menu that appeared to produce a checklist of fields that could be unticked & re-arranged.

I've updated to 2.14.22 and the right-click functionality has vanished! Searched everywhere I can think of, can't find these settings or any clues in changelogs.

I'm sure I'm missing something here, can someone help me out?

Comment: Have you been using QGIS 2.16 or 2.18 previously?

Comment: I can't say for 2.14 but in 2.18.14 the right-click still permit to access the reorder menu

Comment: Hi Kazuhito, I was on 2.14 previously

Comment: As @J.R commented, I was thinking of functionality 2.16+.... it's interesting it was working in previous 2.14 version.

Comment: May have got my wires crossed with versions (uninstalled prior to updating yesterday) in any case am trying a further update to 2.18 now, failing that may try rolling back. Thanks for suggestions, will post back here when I figure this out.

Comment: UPDATE fixed this problem by updating QGIS to 2.18.16. Could not find a solution in 2.14 (there is a work-around by changing the "Edit widget" property to "Hidden" in the Fields section of Layer Properties, then re-opening the attribute table, but it takes too long with lots of fields). Thanks JR for the suggestion.